# Capturing log information from bunch of python functions in single file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have 3 scripts. one is `starttest.py` which kicks the execution of methods called in `test.py`. Methods are defined in `module.py`.

There are many print statements in each of file and I want to capture each print statement in my log file from `Starttest.py` file itself. I tried using `sys.stdout` in `starttest.py` file but this function only takes print statements from `starttest.py` file. It does not have any control on `test.py` and `module.py` file print statements.

Any suggestions to capture the print statements from all of the files in a single place only?

Comment: Consider using the [`logging` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) instead of `print` statements.

Comment: Will Logging module help me to capture print statements as well along with other level of debug information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before importing anything from `test.py` or `module.py`, replace tye `sys.stdout` file object with one of your liking:

```
import sys

sys.stdout = open("test-output.txt", "wt")

# Import the rest
```

If you're running on a Unix-like operating system, there is a safer method that does not need to replace the file object reference.  Specially since overwriting `sys.stdout` does not guarantee that previous object is destroyed:

```
import os
import sys

fd = os.open("test-output.txt", os.O_WRONLY | os.O_CREAT, 0644)
os.dup2(fd, sys.stdout.fileno())
os.close(fd)
```

Note that the above trick is used by almost all *daemonization* implementations for Python.

Even though not directly related, remember also that you can use your shell to redirect command output to a file (works on Windows too):

```
python starttest.py >test-output.txt
```

Comment: Thanks . It was helpful !!!   Earlier also i tried sys.stdout function to keep logs into single file but it didnot worked. And now it worked. I also kept sys.stdout = open("test-output.txt", "wt") below all import declarations and it worked !!! Surprised

Comment: @user2033758: Now your problem is solved, if you tick this answer, it will acknowledge the answerer and mark the question as closed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe look at the logging module that comes with python